# how does the method of resume works or dispatcher works in the coroutines of Kotlin, which lead to different output sequence

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Below are two snippet, they are almost the same, except one has thread in suspend coroutine and another not.

The first code is:

```
suspend fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    log(0)

    coroutineScope {
        log(1)
        val result = suspendCoroutine<String> { continuation ->
            log(2)
            Thread {
                log(3)
                continuation.resume("cup")
                log(4)
            }.start()
        }
        log("5 $result")
    }

    log(6)

    Thread.sleep(100)
}
```

Its output is:

```
    [main] 0
    [main] 1
    [main] 2
    [Thread-0] 3
    [Thread-0] 5 cup
    [Thread-0] 6
    [Thread-0] 4
```

and second code is:

```
suspend fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    log(0)

    coroutineScope {
        log(1)
        val result = suspendCoroutine<String> { continuation ->
            log(2)
            // we don’t use thread in suspend coroutine
            // Thread {
                log(3)
                continuation.resume("cup")
                log(4)
            // }.start()
        }
        log("5 $result")
    }

    log(6)

    Thread.sleep(100)
}
```

Its output is:

```
    [main] 0
    [main] 1
    [main] 2
    [main] 3
    [main] 4
    [main] 5 cup
    [main] 6
```

and the log function is:

```
fun <T> log(t: T) {
    println("[${Thread.currentThread().name}] ${t.toString()}")
}
```

Why one’s output sequence is  0->1->2->3->5->6->4, and another is 0->1->2->3->4->5->6。

Answer (score 2):

The first thing to note is that the result will be different with `runBlocking`.

```
fun main() = runBlocking { ...
```

With `runBlocking`, the coroutine will be confined into the event loop.

Then by calling `continuation.resume`, the created thread will hand the result to the coroutine, which will get executed by the main thread. And `4` and `5 6` will be logged concurrently. It can be `4 5 6`, `5 4 6`, or `5 6 4`.

---

> `suspend fun main` does not define any `Dispatcher`, so when the `Continuation` is resumed then it uses the current thread. There is not thread constraints.

https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/1591#issuecomment-537421694

So this is like launching a coroutine in [`Unconfined`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-dispatchers/-unconfined.html).

Two things can happen when you resume the coroutine. Let's look at the definition of `suspendCoroutine`.

```
public suspend inline fun <T> suspendCoroutine(crossinline block: (Continuation<T>) -> Unit): T =
    suspendCoroutineUninterceptedOrReturn { c: Continuation<T> ->
        val safe = SafeContinuation(c.intercepted())
        block(safe)
        safe.getOrThrow()
    }
```

The `getOrThrow` in main, and the `reusme` in the new thread will race to set the `result` field of the `SafeContinuation`.

If `getOrThrow` wins, the coroutine will be suspended. The new thread will execute the rest of the coroutine by itself (because it is unconfined). It can only log `4` after running the continuation.
I.e. the result is `5 6 4`.

If `resume` wins, `getOrThrow` will return the actual result, and the coroutine will not be suspended. The new thread does not try to run the continuation, because the main thread will keep on executing the rest of the coroutine.
Again, `4` and `5 6` will be logged concurrently.

You can make `resume` win by `sleep`ing main after starting the new thread.

---

If you have looked at the code and understood the previous paragraphs. I hope it is now obvious why the result is always 4 5 6 when you `resume` synchronously inside `suspendCoroutine`. Because `resume` is always called before `getOrThrow`.

---

I think it is possible to use Kotlin coroutines proficiently without understanding any of the above. Just use confined coroutines and be done with it.

Answer (score 1):

```kotlin
suspendCoroutine<String> { continuation ->
    log(2)
    log(3)
    continuation.resume("cup")
    log(4)
}
```

When you resume the continuation while still within the `suspendCoroutine` call, no suspension actually happens and `suspendCoroutine` simply returns the value you resumed it with. So in this case the execution order is completely sequential and deterministic.

```
val result = suspendCoroutine<String> { continuation ->
    log(2)
    thread {
        log(3)
        continuation.resume("cup")
        log(4)
    }
}
log("5 $result")
```

Here suspension actually happens because `suspendCoroutine` completes while the continuation is not yet resumed. This means that the dispatcher is free to run other coroutines and true concurrency ensues. You may get several different orderings, depending on timing. The ordering 2-3-4-5 is also possible, as well as what you observed.

Answer (score 0):

Because there are no guarantees about the order in which coroutines that run in parallel are executed.

`Continuation.resume` specifies the following behaviour:

> Resumes the execution of the corresponding coroutine passing value as the return value of the last suspension point.

It does not specify when or where it will execute that code. What you are seeing are optimizations where code is executed directly in the resuming thread if that does not violate other guarantees for performance reasons.

As an exercise you can go through all the suspensions in your code and derive the following rules that any output must follow:

1. `log(0)` first
2. `log(6)` after `log(5)`.
3. `log(1)` after `log(0)`.
4. `log(2)` after `log(1)`
5. `log(3)` after `log(2)`
6. `log(5)` after `continuation.resume` (Resume causes `suspendCoroutine` to emit a return value)
7. `log(4)` after `continuation.resume`

There is no requirement that `log(4)` executes before `log(5)` or `log(6)` through the order of suspending operations, so its entirely implementation-dependant.

Comment: There is just one coroutine in the question.